# How to display errors while trying to display images in php?

Tags: gd, jpeg, php

I'm using php gd library to generate image/jpeg.

I'm getting the error message:

```
image xyz.php cannot be displayed because it contains errors
```

How can I get the specific error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want to log the errors in image files (binary files), you shouldn't just print them, but instead - log them to external file.

When you are outputting the image to browser, there should be no output before and neither ater.

Comment out the line where you print image (`imagejpeg()`), and there should be no output. If there is, you have a problem.

Side note: And make sure you are not doing the mistake of outputing the image into the HTML document directly. You have to make separate PHP file for image, and then link it into document like this:

```
<img src="image.php" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 3):

either comment out `header` with image Content-type or send your errors into error log and tail them from there

Oh, of course you have to request the image url directly, not watch it linked from some HTML, if you choose the former.

Comment: commenting header displays some junk.
CODE:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_log','log.log');`

I used above for logging , didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Most chance to get error due to path problem,In my case font path was wrong,So please check all given paths are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

That is a message from your browser, actually - it means that the data that has been output doesn't match the image format. This might be various things - extraneous space at the start/end of your PHP files, error messages (that are output to the browser by default), etc.

If you want to see the PHP errors, set `display_errors` to `0`, check where your PHP error log is and watch that log.